# Convert image to base64 in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, base64

How can I convert it to base64? I able to store it, but how to get base64 from there?

I using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/signature_pad/example

```
  final image = await sign.getData();
  var data = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  var savedDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String appDocPath = savedDir.path;
  
  await Directory('$appDocPath/Signature/').create(recursive: true);
  var file = File(file).writeAsBytesSync(data.buffer.asInt8List());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the file and do like this

```
List<int> imageBytes = await File(file).readAsBytes();
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
print(base64Image);
```

**Full code**

```
final image = await sign.getData();
var data = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
var savedDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = savedDir.path;
await Directory('$appDocPath/Signature/').create(recursive: true);
var file = File(file).writeAsBytesSync(data.buffer.asInt8List());

List<int> imageBytes = await File(file).readAsBytes();
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
print(base64Image);
```

Are there any cleaner way ?